# Recording a VNC Sessions

Tags: flv, vnc, flvplayback, vnc-server

I am currently recording a vnc sessions using vnc2flv. But the flv file i get is very huge in size.  For a recording of 5 seconds the file size is around 10 mb.  What values should i provide for the paramters so that i get a proper flv file.  Also the flv file generated is not playable using vnc media player